# MikroC VS xc8 codes

Tags: microcontroller, proteus, xc8

[image]I have found this codes for controlling DC motor speed using PWM by connecting two switches to increase and decrease the PWM value. The problem is this codes is in MiKroc and my compiler is XC8. May i know what changes should i change for the codes to work in protues.

```
  #define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000L


 //#define RS RB0
 //#define EN RB1
 //#define D4 RD4
 //#define D5 RD5
 //#define D6 RD6
 //#define D7 RD7

#include <xc.h>


// BEGIN CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = HS // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT enabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR enabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit SerialProgramming Enable bit (RB3 is digital I/O, HV on MCLR must be used for   programming)
#pragma config CPD = OFF // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM   code protection off)
#pragma config WRT = OFF // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write   protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
     #pragma config CP = OFF // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit   (Code    protection off)
     //END CONFIG

  int main()
  {
    short duty  = 0; //initial value for duty

  TRISD = 0xFF; //PORTD as input
  TRISC = 0x00; //PORTC as output
  TRISB = 0x00; //PORTB as output
  PORTB = 0x02; //Run motor in anticlock wise

  PWM1_Init(1000);  //Initialize PWM1
  PWM1_Start();  //start PWM1
  PWM1_Set_Duty(duty); //Set current duty for PWM1

  while (1)        // endless loop
  {
 if (RD0==0 && duty<250) //if button on RD0 pressed      
 {       
   __delay_ms(40);       
    duty = duty + 10;  //increment current_duty     
    PWM1_Set_Duty(duty);  //Change the duty cycle      
 }     
 if (RD1==0 && duty >0) //button on RD1 pressed
 {
  __delay_ms(40);
   duty = duty - 10;  //decrement duty
   PWM1_Set_Duty(duty);
 }
  __delay_ms(10);     // slow down change pace a little
 }
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean Proteus? I don't see any library's either.

Comment: yea i mean Proteus, i just medified the codes, plz chq back

Comment: Well, we can't really guess what your problem is. If you list the _error messages_ you get when compiling, maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the three PWM-related functions are not declared nor defined anywhere:

```
PWM1_Init(1000);  //Initialize PWM1
PWM1_Start();  //start PWM1
PWM1_Set_Duty(duty); //Set current duty for PWM1
```

Presumably, the MikroC environment includes everything automatically, causing a lot of surprise when porting to less insane environments.

I don't know what MikroC is or does, but to make your code run, you need to declare and define the three functions `PWM1_Init()`, `PWM1_Start(void)`, and `PWM1_Set_Duty()`. Perhaps you can copy them from MikroC.